# How to use the TDengine stmt API in python?

Tags: python

Which is the recommended way to insert multiple rows of data into TDengine tables in Python language?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to insert 3 rows of data with Python connector.

```py
from taos import *

conn = connect()

dbname = "pytest_taos_stmt"
conn.exec("drop database if exists %s" % dbname)
conn.exec("create database if not exists %s" % dbname)
conn.select_db(dbname)

conn.exec(
    "create table if not exists log(ts timestamp, bo bool, nil tinyint, \
        ti tinyint, si smallint, ii int, bi bigint, tu tinyint unsigned, \
        su smallint unsigned, iu int unsigned, bu bigint unsigned, \
        ff float, dd double, bb binary(100), nn nchar(100), tt timestamp)",
)

stmt = conn.statement("insert into log values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")

params = new_multi_binds(16)
params[0].timestamp((1626861392589, 1626861392590, 1626861392591))
params[1].bool((True, None, False))
params[2].tinyint([-128, -128, None]) # -128 is tinyint null
params[3].tinyint([0, 127, None])
params[4].smallint([3, None, 2])
params[5].int([3, 4, None])
params[6].bigint([3, 4, None])
params[7].tinyint_unsigned([3, 4, None])
params[8].smallint_unsigned([3, 4, None])
params[9].int_unsigned([3, 4, None])
params[10].bigint_unsigned([3, 4, None])
params[11].float([3, None, 1])
params[12].double([3, None, 1.2])
params[13].binary(["abc", "dddafadfadfadfadfa", None])
params[14].nchar(["涛思数据", None, "a long string with 中文字符"])
params[15].timestamp([None, None, 1626861392591])
stmt.bind_param_batch(params)
stmt.execute()


result = stmt.use_result()
assert result.affected_rows == 3
result.close()

result = conn.query("select * from log")
for row in result:
    print(row)
result.close()
stmt.close()
conn.close()
```